# Conditional Cross Join Postgresql

Tags: postgresql, cross-join

I have two tables, Table A and Table B. The two tables do not have common columns.

Table A

| Name |
| --- |
| Name 1 |
| Name 2 |

Table B

| Attribute | Value |
| --- | --- |
| Attribute 1 | Value 1 |
| Attribute 2 | Value 2 |

I tried cross-joining the two tables using this query

```
select t1.name, t2.attribute, t2.value from table1 t1 cross join table2 t2;
```

The result was

| t1.name | t2.attribute | t2.value |
| --- | --- | --- |
| Name 1 | Attribute 1 | Value 1 |
| Name 1 | Attribute 2 | Value 2 |
| Name 2 | Attribute 1 | Value 1 |
| Name 2 | Attribute 2 | Value 2 |

However, my expected result was

| t1.name | t2.attribute | t2.value |
| --- | --- | --- |
| Name 2 | Attribute 1 | Value 1 |
| Name 2 | Attribute 2 | Value 2 |

Some context: I inserted these values through a POST API request (In the post request to insert Name 1, I didn't fill in any values related to Table 2, which is why I was expecting only Name 2 to show up in the results.

Comment: Given the example data you gave, the cross join is returning correctly. A cross join just returns all possible row pairs between the two tables.

Comment: However, I want the query to only return Name 2. Is there another way to do it?

Comment: add WHERE clause; WHERE t1.name = 'Name 2'

Comment: But this defeats the purpose of the query. I want to the query to automatically filter out non-matching values

Comment: If you want to match the 2 tables you must have a common column. It sounds as if there is some matching that you expect to happen but you have to have an explicit column(s) for the database to be able to do that match.